# Is global memory contiguous in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am new to OpenCL and trying to do 2D scan using global memory in OpenCL.

I am having some invalid values in the output array which makes doubt 
if global memory is contiguous. Because by running the following kernel, I found some rubbish value in the output array.

Here is my kernel. Both input and output are 8 by 8 2-d array.

```
#define SWAP(a,b) {__global uint *tmp=a;a=b;b=tmp;}
__kernel void 2dScan(
    const __global  uint * const input,
    __global  uint * const output,
    __global uint *lb,
    __global uint *lc
    )
{
    const uint x = get_global_id(0);
    const uint y = get_global_id(1);
    const uint xm = get_global_size(0);
    const uint ym = get_global_size(1);
    uint gs = get_global_size(0) * get_global_size(1);
    uint index = y * xm + x;

    lb[index] = lc[index] = input[index];
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    for(uint s = 1; s < gs; s <<= 1) {
        if(index > (s-1)) {
            lc[index] = lb[index]+lb[index-s];
        } else {
            lc[index] = lb[index];
        }
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
        SWAP(lb,lc);
    }
    output[index]= lb[index];

}
```

Thank you very much if you can give some suggestions.

Comment: I think you mean "contiguous".

Answer (score 0):

I have a doubt, What is rubbish value? an uninitialized one or an incorrect one?

In my opinion, there is a problem in your for loop. Your accesses are not deterministic, this is, you cannot ensure which will the result for, for example, output[2].

For example, the work-item #2 performs inside the loop (s = 1): lc[2] = lb[2] + lb[1];
Ok, the question is: the value of lb[1], was already modified by the work-item #1 or not? Your barrier synchronized the work-items belonging to the same work-group. I think that the accesses in `lc[index] = lb[index]+lb[index-s];`  are going outside of the workgroup 'limits' because of the `s` value causing the non-deterministic problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. By rubbish value, I meant an uninitialized value. Now I understand what the problem is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `lb` and `lc` in each work item. Therefore the results are undefined, since OpenCL has no synchronization between global items. `barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);` synchronizes the local work group at global memory scope.

The results you will get are based on the schedule pattern, and are not predictable in any way. However, it will only happen in local group boundaries.

You need to change your algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand `barrier(CLK_GLOCAL_MEM_FENCE);` won't synchronize global items. Thank you very much!